# Call missing arguments from parent environment

Tags: r

I could not find a clever way to recover missing arguments from parent enviroment (or re building it) when there are not provided

This fails using `missing`

```
fooBar <- function(x,y){
  if(missing(y)) {
    y = get0("y", inherits = TRUE)
    x + y
  } else {
    x + y
  }
}
y <- 1
fooBar(x = 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this ?

```
fooBar <- function(x,y){
  if(missing(y)) y <- eval.parent(quote(y))
  x + y
}
y <- 1
fooBar(x = 2)
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution but I am upset with it

```
fooBar <- function(x,y=NULL){
  if(is.null(y)) {
    rm(y)  # otherwise, get0 recovers NULL :S
    y = get0("y", inherits = TRUE)
    x + y
  } else {
    x + y
  }
}
y <- 1
fooBar(x = 2)
```

Comment: Why is it upsetting?

Comment: R walks up the parent environments to search by default, so you can simplify this function to `fooBar <- function(x,y=NULL){
  if(is.null(y)) rm(y);
  x + y
}`